# $\sigma$ de Rham p-adic Galois representations

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

In the paper of Liang Xiao. [Tensor being crystalline implies each factor being crystalline up to twist](https://www.math.uci.edu/~lxiao/files/papers/appendix.pdf), the author says that a $G_K$ representation $\rho$ is de Rham if and only if  $\rho$ is $\sigma$-de Rham for all $\sigma\in Gal(K/Q_p)$ in the proof of theorem 1, where $K$ is a finite Galois extension of $Q_p$. I don't know how to prove this.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V \otimes_{\mathbf{Q}_p} B_{dR} = \bigoplus_\sigma \left( V \otimes_{K, \sigma} B_{dR}\right)$.

Comment: So this means that $V$ is de Rham as a representation over $Q_p$ if and only if $V$ is $\sigma$-de Rham as a representation over K for all $\sigma$ ? I have not noticed different fields here before...

Comment: And thanks your answers!